# Regular Expression in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, controls

I need a Regular Expression for "Atleast 6 characters with no spaces"
Please help

Comment: Any restrictions what characters it should be? Anything that is not a space? Letters, numbers?

Comment: Yes any character except space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- To allow anything other than whitespace `^\S{6,}$`
- To allow only alphabets: `^[a-zA-Z]{6,}$`
- To allow word chars (alphanumeric and _): `^\w{6,}$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use \w{6,}

Also FYI:

you can use [Regex Coach](http://weitz.de/regex-coach/)  for Regular Expression experiments.
It is easy to play with Regular Expressions by using tools like Regex Coach.

Answer (score 0):

For literally any six non-space characters (other than newlines, depending on options):

```
[^ ]{6,}
```

For six non-whitespace characters:

```
\S{6,}
```

Comment: In both cases it should be {6,} since vaibhav states "at least 6 characters"